# Moving IRIS db in runtime?

Tags: intersystems-iris

I'm almost running out of disk space so I want to move 1 DB to a different hard drive.
It's a rather simple but lengthy action during a shutdown of IRIS.
But is this somehow possible under runtime in a stand-alone installation?
I'm looking for kind of a "local failover"
note: Mirror or Shadow is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input by Vitaliy Serdtsev · Apr 12, 2021

If something does not suit in the bundle
[Backup.General:ExternalFreeze()/ExternalThaw()](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=Backup.General#ExternalFreeze),
then can try the bundle
[SYS.Database:DismountDatabase()/MountDatabase()](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=SYS.Database#DismountDatabase).
Or at all [SYS.Database:Copy()](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=SYS.Database#Copy).

Answer (score 0):

See the excellent reply in Developer Community
I'll place the content in a different Answer